# Как достучаться до сервера?

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование

Познакомился с нодой совсем недавно и после php всё кругом идет, так что не ругайте.

Запускаю сервер:

```
user@host: sudo nodejs server.js
Server running at http://localhost:8080/
```

Код сервера:

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 8080;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

И логично что сервер запустился на локалке:
user@host: curl localhost:8080
Hello World

При изменении hostname на домен, консоль выдаёт:
Server running at http://moidomen.com:8080/
Только вот при обращении к moidomen.com:8080, браузер после пары минут загрузки выдаёт ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
Что я делаю не так? :)

Comment: Домен-то ведёт на тот компьютер, на котором вы ноду запускаете?

Comment: Порт 8080 у домена `moidomen.ru` открыт?